# Errores con variables globales. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

quería saber si podeís ayudarme. Es la primera vez que programo en python y no sé muy bien como va, solo he programado en java. Lo siento si tengo fallos. El caso es que estoy haciendo un programa , con una clase y varias funciones def, pero me da varios errores sobre que las variables no están definidas, pero si que lo están, o por lo menos creo que sí. Aquí os dejo un pequeño ejemplo de como lo tengo:

```
class Cliente:

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
#server = ('', 69) #TFTP utiliza UDP como protocolo de transporte en el puerto 69
BLCKSIDE = 512
MAXBLCKSIDE = 32768
MAXDUP = 10
RETRANS = 3
SOCK_TO= 5
MINBLCKSIDE = 9

def __init__(self, ipLocal = "", puerto = 69):
    self.filename = " "
    self.mode = b"ascii"
    self.opcode = None
    self.ipLocal = ipLocal
    self.puerto = puerto
    self.timeout = timeout
    self.sigBlock = 0
    self.numBlock = {}
    self.buffer = {}
    self.data = {}
    self.contDup = 0
    self.dup = {}
    self.duracion = 0 #tiempo desde que empieza hasta que termina
    self.bps = 0
    self.kbps = 0
    self.inicio = 0
    self.fin = 0
    self.bytes = 0


iter = True #Do-While
while iter == True:
    op = menu()
    self.inicio = time.time() 
    if op == 1: #SWITCH-CASE
        solicitud_RRQ()
        respuesta()
    elif op == 2:
        solicitud_WRQ()
        respuesta()
    else:
        print("Para salir. Introduce QUIT")
        entrada = input("TFTP@UDP > ")
        if entrada.rstrip() == "QUIT":
            sock.close()
            sys.exit(0)
    iter = False

def menu():
    op = 0
    print('elige una opción.\n'
        + '1 --> Lerctura del fichero.\n'
        + '2 --> Escribir en el fichero.\n'
        + '3 --> Salir.\n')
    try: 
        op = int(input())
    except ValueError:
        print('El valor introducido debe ser un número en el rango (1-3). Por favor vuelva a intentarlo.\n')
        op = int(input())

    return op

def tiempo(self):
    self.duracion = self.fin - self.inicio
    if self.duracion == 0:
        self.duracion = 1
    self.bps = (self.bytes*8.0) / self.duracion
    self.kbps = self.bps /1024.0

def solicitud_RRQ(self):
    self.opcode = 1
    self.mode = self.mode.encode('ascii')

    print('Por favor introduzca el nombre del archivo.\n')
    self.filename = str(input("TFTP@UDP > "))
    self.filename = self.filename.encode('ascii')

    frmt = b"!H"
    frmt += b"%dsx" % len(self.filename)
    frmt += b"5sx"

    datagrama = struct.pack(frmt, self.opcode, filename, self.mode)
    self.sock.sendto(datagrama, """server""")
    return self.filename
#Tienes que mirar los ACks, sigBloque 
def respuesta(self):
    while True:
        datagrama = self.sock.recvfrom()
        opcode = struct.unpack("!H", datagrama[:2])
        self.numBlock += struct.unpack("!H", datagrama[2:4])
        if opcode == 3:
            (self.opcode, self.buffer, self.numBlock, self.data) = data_decode()
            for i in self.numBlock:
                if self.numBlock !=i :
                    f = open (self.filemane, 'r')
                    for linea in f:
                        f.write(self.data)
                    f.close()
                else:
                    self.dup += 1
            self.numBlock = numBlock
            numBlock += 1
            ack_encode(numBlock)
        elif opcode == 5:
            (self.opcode, self.errCode, self.errMsg, self.errMsgs) = err_decode(self)
            print(self.errMsgs)

def solicitud_WRQ(self):
    self.opcode = 2
    self.mode = self.mode.encode('ascii')

    print('Por favor introduzca el nombre del archivo.\n')
    self.filename = str(input("TFTP@UDP > "))
    self.filename = self.filename.encode('ascii')

    frmt = b"!H"
    frmt += b"%dsx" % len(self.filename)
    frmt += b"5sx"

    datagrama = struct.pack(frmt, self.opcode, self.filename, self.mode)
    self.sock.sendto(datagrama, """server""")
    return self.filename

def ack_encode(*argv): #quitar esto para TCP
    self.opcode = 4
    for arg in argv:
        self.buffer = struct.pack(str("!HH"), self.opcode, self.numBlock)
    return self.buffer

def ack_decode(self):#quitar esto para TCP
    self.opcode = 4
    self.numBlock = 0
    if len(self.buffer)>4:
        self.buffer = self.buffer[0:4]
        self.opcode, self.numBlock = struct.unpack(str("!HH"), self.buffer)

    return self

def data_decode(self):
    self.opcode = 3
    self.data = None
    (self.numBock) = struct.unpack(str("!H"), self.buffer[2:4])
    self.data = self.buffer[4:]
    return self

def err_decode(self):
    self.opcode = 5
    self.errCode = 0
    self.errMsg = None
    self.errMsgs = {
        1: b"Archivo no encontrado.",
        2: b"Violacion de acceso.",
        3: b"Disco lleno o asignacion superada.",
        4: b"Operacion TFTP ilegal.",
        5: b"ID de transferencia desconocida.",
        6: b"El archivo ya existe.",
        7: b"No hay tal usuario"
    }
    longBuf = len(self.buffer)
    if longBuf == 4: 
        frmt = b"!HH"
        self.opcode,self.errCode = struct.unpack(frmt, self.buffer)
    else: 
        frmt = b"!HH%dsx" % (len(self.buffer)-5)
        self.opcode, self.errCode, self.errMsg = struct.unpack(frmt, self.buffer)
    return self
```

Sé que tendré muchos fallos, asi que me disculpo. Todavía tengo que modificar algunas cosas, pero si no arreglo esto no creo que pueda ejecutarlo.

Siento las molestias, muchas gracias.

Comment: El código que has pegado no está correctamente indentado. Por ejemplo, entiendo que todos los `def`deberían estar dentro de la `class`, pero están al mismo nivel. Y el  `while iter==True` ¿a qué método pertenece? Estos problemas de indentación suelen ser culpa del corta y pega en Stack Overflow. Aquí https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE explica cómo hacerlo para que quede bien. Por otro lado no muestras qué error es el que te ocurre.

Answer (score 1):

Que tal amigo no te preocupes creo que a todos nos pasa cuando pasamos de un lenguaje indentado a uno dentado:

- los def que quieres que vallan dentro de la clase tienen que ir dentados para que tome en cuenta que pertenecen a esa clase
- las variables globales las tienes que declarar afuera de la clase yo lo coloco siempre al inicio de los documentos despues de las importaciones